# How do I replace a Maven repository with a local directory after it is defined in a Gradle build?

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to write tests for a build process, so my unit test wants to replace the actual repository locations with local locations to avoid poisoning the real server. (Plus, I suppose, the person running the test might not have access to publish anyway.)

In the build itself:

```
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = 'snapshot'
            url = "${artifactory_contextUrl}/libs-snapshot-local"
            credentials {
                username artifactory_user
                password artifactory_password
            }
        }

        maven {
            name = 'release'
            url = "${artifactory_contextUrl}/libs-release-local"
            credentials {
                username artifactory_user
                password artifactory_password
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my test build, I'm trying to override it with this:

```
publishing {
    repositories {
        getByName('snapshot') {
            url = uri('/tmp/local-repo/snapshots')
        }
        getByName('release') {
            url = uri('/tmp/local-repo/release')
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the build, I get:

```
Execution failed for task ':publishMavenJavaPublicationToReleaseRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'release'
   > Authentication scheme 'all'(Authentication) is not supported by protocol 'file'
```

There are a lot of posts out on the web about this specific error, but it always seems to be people who accidentally put a file path in when they should have put a URI. I'm putting in a URI deliberately, though, so is there a way to get this to work?

I have also tried this:

```
publishing {
    repositories {
        clear()
        maven {
            name = 'snapshot'
            url = uri('/tmp/local-repo/snapshots')
        }
        maven {
            name = 'release'
            url = uri('/tmp/local-repo/release')
        }
    }
}
```

That fails with:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'test-common-plugin1913987501683151177'.
> Exception thrown while executing model rule: PublishingPluginRules#publishing(ExtensionContainer)
  > Cannot add task 'publishMavenJavaPublicationToSnapshotRepository' as a task with that name already exists.
```

I was surprised that deleting all the repositories doesn't also delete all the tasks they own. When I try to programmatically delete the task it's complaining about, Gradle claims that it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I ended up having to read the source of Gradle (again), but I found a way to do it. Essentially you can directly set `credentials` back to `null`, like this:

```
publishing {
    repositories {
        getByName('snapshot') {
            url = uri('/tmp/local-repo/snapshots')
            configuredCredentials = null
        }
        getByName('release') {
            url = uri('/tmp/local-repo/release')
            configuredCredentials = null
        }
    }
}
```